# Weird Bug With Cursor.Hide() function

Tags: c#, cursor, picturebox

I'm working on a Battleship game project and I made a control named `GraphicCell` that inherits from the `PictureBox` class but is functioning as a button for the board.

The main difference from a normal button is that it hides the cursor when you hover on it. It also has a background image and a parameter named `locked` that I'm using to lock the computer's board (the player can't play on this board). The cursor is not hidden on the locked ones.

**My Problem: When I hover over a non-locked `GraphicCell` the cursor is hidden like it should, and for the `locked` ones it shows the cursor like it should, but when I hover over a `locked` one, the cursor doesn't hide again when I hover over a non-locked `GraphicCell`.**

> GIF exemple for the bug: https://gyazo.com/750a2688a3d33d49462ff6b6e68533d1
>
> Left (User's Board) - Not Locked
>
> Right (PC's board) - Locked

**Code: (Bug should be in the `MouseEnterEvent` / `MouseLeaveEvent` functinons)**

```
  public class GraphicCell : PictureBox
  {
    enum SquareImage {None, Empty, Bombed};
    readonly int x, y;
    readonly Square s;
    bool locked;

    public GraphicCell(int x, int y, Square s, bool locked = false)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.s = s;
        this.locked = locked;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
        this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.water;
        this.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(MouseEnterEvent);
        this.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(MouseLeaveEvent);
    }

    public bool Locked { get { return locked; } set { locked = value; } }

    public void Update(Result r)
    {
        if (r != Result.None)
        {
            locked = true;

            switch (r)
            {
                case (Result.Miss):
                    ChangeImage(SquareImage.Empty);
                    break;

                case (Result.Hit):
                case (Result.ShipDestroyed):
                case (Result.Victory):
                    ChangeImage(SquareImage.Bombed);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ChangeImage(SquareImage si)
    {
        switch (si)
        {
            case (SquareImage.None):
            this.Image = null;
                break;

            case (SquareImage.Empty):
                    this.Image = Properties.Resources.empty;
                break;

            case (SquareImage.Bombed):
                    this.Image = Properties.Resources.bombed;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void MouseEnterEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!locked)
        {
            this.Image = Properties.Resources.water_bomb;
            Cursor.Hide();
        }
    }

    private void MouseLeaveEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Show();

        if (!locked)
        {
            if (this.Image != null)
                this.Image = null;
        }
    }

    public Square GetSquare()
    { return this.s; }

    public int GetX()
    { return this.x; }

    public int GetY()
    { return this.y; }
}
```

## Edit: Problem Solved

Problem fixed thanks to "OldBoyCoder" & "Hans Passant".

Turns out that the `Cursor.Show()`/`Cursor.Hide()` methods use a counter, so the problem was that in the `MouseLeaveEvent` the `Cursor.Show()` method was called even if the cursor is already shown, so the `Cursor.Show()` method was called sometimes more then once and it made the counter go higher then 1, which is what caused the bug.

(For exemple if the counter of `Cursor.Show()` is 2 and I call `Cursor.Hide()` the cursor remains shown since 2 > 1)

**Fix:**

Fixed by using the bool `locked` to make sure `Cursor.Show()` is being called only once.

Changed:

```
private void MouseLeaveEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Show();

    if (!locked)
    {
        if (this.Image != null)
            this.Image = null;
    }
}
```

To:

```
private void MouseLeaveEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!locked)
    {
        Cursor.Show();

        if (this.Image != null)
            this.Image = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is buggy, the number of Show() calls must equal the number of Hide() calls.  It uses a simple counter internally.  The bug is that you call Show() even though you did not call Hide().  So the internal count is now 2.  That goes wrong the next time, calling Hide() again does not hide the cursor since the count is now 1.  It is much easier to use the Control.Cursor property, add an empty cursor to your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a full answer as I don't have a solution yet but calls to Show and Hide must be balanced as there is an internal counter:

From:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide);k(Hide);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

The Show and Hide method calls must be balanced. For every call to the Hide method there must be a corresponding call to the Show method.

All those Show calls you're making need to be balanced out with Hides.

Comment: Yes, seems like that was the problem, called "Show" 2 times in a row and "Hide" only once after. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You never set locked back to false in method

```
public void Update(Result r)
```

Comment: This function is called only when the control is clicked (code is on form's code).
This bug happens when I hover over the GraphicCells, so this functinon was never called...

Answer (score 0):

You can call `vSetCursor(eCursorOperation.Show)` or `vSetCursor(eCursorOperation.Hide)` in any order as many times as you want.

```
enum eCursorOperation
{
    Show,
    Hide
}

// Since the cursor is showing to start with assume the internal counter is set to 1 - fingers crossed
private int GiCursorShowCount = 1; 

private void vSetCursor(eCursorOperation ecYourChoice)
{
    switch (ecYourChoice)
    {
        case eCursorOperation.Show:
            while (GiCursorShowCount < 1)
            {
                Cursor.Show();
                GiCursorShowCount++;
            }
            break;
        case eCursorOperation.Hide:
            while (GiCursorShowCount > 0)
            {
                Cursor.Hide();
                GiCursorShowCount--;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```